# How to use summarise function in dplyr with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am working with a time-series cross-country dataset covering the period from 2003 to 2018. Each entry in the database corresponds to a protest event, the number of participants, level of engagement of the security services, and level of participant violence. I have multiple observations per year per country. I want to create a new `df` that counts the number of protests for each country (`Count`), the average number of participants (`AvgParticipants`), the average security services engagement (`AvgSecurity`), and the average level of participant violence (`AvgPartViolence`). Here is the code I have written thus far:

```
# Creating Yearly Protest Count Data
# Load packages
library(dplyr)

# Set working directory 
setwd("~/Desktop/Cooptation and Protest")

# Load data
dat <- read.csv("reports.csv")

# Subset to relevant variables
dat <- dat %>%
  select(cowcode, event_date, side, scope, part_violence, sec_engagement,
         numparticipants)

# Convert event_date to only year
dat$event_date <-  as.Date(dat$event_date)
dat$year <- as.numeric(format(dat$event_date,'%Y'))

my_summary_data <- dat %>%
  group_by(year, cowcode) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  summarise(AvgSecurity = mean(sec_engagement)) %>%
  summarise(AvgPartviolence = mean(part_violence))
```

I have no issue when I run `summarise(Count = n())`, but I can't get running `summarise(AvgSecurity = mean(sec_engagement))` and  `summarise(AvgPartviolence = mean(part_violence))` to work. Any advice would be appreciated. Below are some data for your convenience.

```
structure(list(cowcode = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), event_date = structure(c(12183, 
15302, 12173, 12173, 12393, 12583), class = "Date"), side = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), scope = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), part_violence = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), sec_engagement = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), numparticipants = c("", 
"", "", "", "2000", ""), year = c(2003, 2011, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2004)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: YOu need to do them all in the same summarize command. Once you `summarize`, the other columns are no longer in the output: `summarise(Count = n(), AvgSecurity = mean(sec_engagement), AvgPartviolence = mean(part_violence))`

Answer (score 1):

The comment has it!

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(list(cowcode = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), event_date = structure(c(12183, 
15302, 12173, 12173, 12393, 12583), class = "Date"), side = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), scope = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), part_violence = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), sec_engagement = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), numparticipants = c("", 
"", "", "", "2000", ""), year = c(2003, 2011, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2004)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

dat$event_date <-  as.Date(dat$event_date)
dat$year <- as.numeric(format(dat$event_date,'%Y'))

my_summary_data <- dat %>%
  group_by(year, cowcode) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(),
           AvgSecurity = mean(sec_engagement),
           AvgPartviolence = mean(part_violence)) 

my_summary_data
```